# MySQL how store timestamp

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I'm using MySQL 5.7.20, Ubuntu 16.04.

My queries are:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE test (ts TIMESTAMP NULL);

mysql> INSERT INTO test VALUES (1513776043);

mysql> SELECT * FROM test;
+---------------------+
| ts                  |
+---------------------+
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
```

As you see, timestamp not saved. How to store timestamp in MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to convert it with `from_unixtime()`, since that is a unix timestamp.

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES (FROM_UNIXTIME(1513776043));
```

Comment: Function from_unixtime depends on timezone of your server, while timestamp not depends on it. For example: set time_zone = '+00:00'; select FROM_UNIXTIME(1513776043);  returns 2017-12-20 13:20:43, set time_zone = '+03:00'; returns: 2017-12-20 16:20:43

Comment: Ok, I have understood. MySQL stores timestamp field as integer, and `select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ts) from test` not depends on timezone